# What exactly does "Per Unit" refer to?

Tags: electromagnetism, vectors, vector-fields

I am currently reading about Gradient , curl and Divergence in Electromagnetics. Here I don't understand a term called " Per unit ".
for example , Divergence is the net outward flux per unit volume . here what is **"per unit volume"** means ?

Comment: Are you familiar with Divergence Theorem? This is what connects the vector operator $\nabla \dot$ what we define as Flux

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per unit volume is just 'one quantity' of whatever unit you are using to measure volume. If you are using cubic meters as units, then 'flux per unit volume' would be $flux/m^{3}$, meaning there is that much flux for every 'one unit of volume' (for every one cubic meter).